# How to add a header and footer to a PDF generated with DOMPDF and Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

Am using [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) in a Laravel 5.8 app

I have a problem with the header and footer.
[Preview PDF](https://gofile.io/?c=WC8dqD)

I have this function to Generate PDF:

```php
public function getProductPdf(Request $request, int $id)
{
    $product = $this->cmsRepository->getProduct($id);
    $data = [
        'title' => 'First PDF for Medium',
        'heading' => 'Hello from 99Points.info',
        'content' => 'Od kilku dni w szeregach Platformy Obywatelskiej trwa czas powyborczych rozliczeń. Kolejni politycy krytykują działania partii pod kierunkiem Grzegorza Schetyny, którego kadencja na stanowisku przewodniczącego kończy się za kilka miesięcy. Walki o przywództwo nie wyklucza Borys Budka. - Jestem skłonny startować w tych wyborach, bo musi być jakiś wybór - powiedział polityk w rozmowie z "Gazetą Wyborczą".'
    ];

    $pdf = \PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif', 'defaultPaperSize' => 'a3'])->loadView('psCMS.prints.product-view', $data);
    return $pdf->download('product-' . $product->id . '-' . now()->toDateString() . '.pdf');
}
```

This is my template to print:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .page-break {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
        /*@page {*/
        /*    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;*/
        /*    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;*/
        /*}*/
        th,
        td,
        p,
        div,
        b {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
        html {
            margin: 40px 50px
        }
        body {
            font-family: DejaVu Sans;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            /*margin: 0px;*/
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        * {
            font-family: DejaVu Sans, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        table {
            font-size: x-small;
        }
        tfoot tr td {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .gray {
            background-color: lightgray
        }
        .information {
            color: black;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .information .logo {
            margin: 5px;
        }
        .information table {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .document {
            padding-bottom: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="information">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="width: 40%;">
                    <h3>John Doe</h3>
                    <pre>
    Street 15
    123456 City
    United Kingdom
    <br/><br/>
    Date: 2018-01-01
    Identifier: #uniquehash
    Status: Paid
    </pre>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <img src="/path/to/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="64" class="logo" />
                </td>
                <td align="right" style="width: 40%;">
                    <h3>CompanyName</h3>
                    <pre>
                        https://company.com
                        Street 26
                        123456 City
                        United Kingdom
                    </pre>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <h1>{{ $heading}}</h1>
    <div class="document">
        <p>{{$content}}</p>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><img src="{{asset('images/meteor-logo.png')}}" alt="" width="150" /></td>
                <td align="right">
                    <h3>Shinra Electric power company</h3>
                    <pre>
                    Company representative name
                    Company address
                    Tax ID
                    phone
                    fax
                </pre>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>From:</strong> Linblum - Barrio teatral</td>
                <td><strong>To:</strong> Linblum - Barrio Comercial</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <table width="100%">
            <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Unit Price $</th>
                    <th>Total $</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Playstation IV - Black</td>
                    <td align="right">1</td>
                    <td align="right">1400.00</td>
                    <td align="right">1400.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Metal Gear Solid - Phantom</td>
                    <td align="right">1</td>
                    <td align="right">105.00</td>
                    <td align="right">105.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Final Fantasy XV - Game</td>
                    <td align="right">1</td>
                    <td align="right">130.00</td>
                    <td align="right">130.00</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                    <td align="right">Subtotal $</td>
                    <td align="right">1635.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                    <td align="right">Tax $</td>
                    <td align="right">294.3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                    <td align="right">Total $</td>
                    <td align="right" class="gray">$ 1929.3</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        Pence poinformował po trwających ponad cztery godziny negocjacjach, że Turcja na 120 godzin zawiesi wszystkie
        operacje militarne, by pozwolić kurdyjskim bojownikom na opuszczenie przygranicznego pasa w północno-wschodniej
        Syrii, a gdy Kurdowie wycofają się, nastąpi rozejm.
        Turcja nie będzie jednak zobligowana do wycofania swoich wojsk z Syrii. Jak pisze AP, cytując przedstawiciela
        amerykańskich władz, oznacza to de facto, że Ankara otrzymała pozwolenie USA na okupowanie bezpiecznej strefy.
        Negocjatorzy obu stron wydali komunikat, w którym napisano, że stworzenie bezpiecznej strefy "będzie egzekwowane
        przede wszystkim przez siły zbrojne Turcji".
        Wiceprezydent podkreślił też, że prezydent Donald Trump zagroził, że jeśli Ankara nie zawiesi operacji
        wojskowych, to on nie wycofa obecnych sankcji nałożonych na Turcję i pozwoli na wdrożenie następnych.
        Dodał, że Ankara i Waszyngton "zobowiązały się do wypracowania pokojowego rozwiązania i przyszłości dla
        bezpiecznej strefy" na północnym wschodzie Syrii. Oznajmił, że amerykańskie siły w Syrii zaczęły już ułatwiać
        Kurdom bezpieczne wycofanie się z przygranicznych terenów.
        Pence powiedział również dziennikarzom, że Ankara obiecała, że jej wojska nie zajmą miasta Kobane (Ajn al-Arab),
        nazywanego ogniskiem zapalnym tego konfliktu. Minister spraw zagranicznych Turcji Mevlut Cavusoglu oznajmił
        jednak, że Ankara nie udzieliła gwarancji dotyczących Kobane, a jej armia jedynie "przerwała operacje". Dodał,
        że status miasta Manbidż "i innych regionów" na północnym wschodzie Syrii, zostanie przedyskutowany z Rosją.
        Kurdyjski polityk Aldar Chalil, komentując warunki rozejmu, powiedział telewizji Al-Arabija, że Erdogan chce
        wedrzeć się na terytorium Syrii na głębokość 32 km, a Kurdowie już wcześniej odrzucili takie rozwiązanie. Dodał,
        że aprobują zawieszenie broni, ale będą się bronić, jeśli zostaną zaatakowani.
        Amerykańscy senatorowie, w tym wpływy sojusznik prezydenta Lindsey Graham, poinformowali, że niezależnie od
        zapowiedzi rozejmu, będą "pełną parą" pracowali nad ustawą w sprawie nowych sankcji na Ankarę.
        "Wspaniałe wiadomości z Turcji"
        Trump podziękował na Twitterze Erodganowi i napisał, że otrzymał "wspaniałe wiadomości z Turcji". "Miliony
        istnień ludzkich będą uratowane!" - dodał. Oznajmił, że w tej sytuacji możliwa jest wizyta Erdogana w USA w
        przyszłym miesiącu.
        Nazwał też prezydenta Turcji "twardym facetem", który "zrobił to, co trzeba". Dodał: "Teraz Kurdowie będą
        bardziej skłonni robić to, co trzeba".
        Przedstawiciel strony tureckiej po negocjacjach powiedział agencji Reutera, że Turcja "dostała dokładnie to,
        czego chciała". Porozumienie pozwala Turcji uwolnić się od nałożonych już sankcji i uniknąć kolejnych, a to
        oznacza, że w żaden sposób nie zostanie ukarana za inwazję w północno-wschodniej Syrii - komentuje AP.
        Reuters przypomina, że ekspedycja sił tureckich zmusiła do ucieczki 200 tys. cywilów. Wzbudziła też niepokój
        wspólnoty międzynarodowej o odrodzenie się Państwa Islamskiego (IS), którego bojownicy są zamknięci w
        kurdyjskich więzieniach.
        Turecka ofensywa wywołała też polityczną burzę w Waszyngtonie, gdzie politycy różnych afiliacji krytykowali
        prezydenta za decyzję o wycofaniu amerykańskich żołnierzy z Syrii, co Ankara uznała za przyzwolenie na podjęcie
        operacji wojennych - komentuje Reuters.
        W środę Trump bronił swojej decyzji, nazywając ją "strategicznie błyskotliwą", ale Izba Reprezentantów tego
        samego dnia przyjęła rezolucję potępiającą decyzję prezydenta o wycofaniu amerykańskich żołnierzy z Syrii.
        Za rezolucją, w liczącej 435 miejsc niższej izbie Kongresu, głosowało 354 kongresmenów, czyli wszyscy Demokraci
        i duża grupa Republikanów. W czwartek głosowanie nad analogiczną rezolucją zapowiedział Senat.
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="footer" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="width: 50%;">
                        &copy; {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.url') }} - All rights reserved.
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" style="width: 50%;">
                        Company Slogan
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I need Header and Footer to be visible on every page in PDF.

The template looks ok, but there is a problem with the header and footer.

Header = John Doe, Company Name, etc.
Footer = Company slogan, @2019-10-17

How can I add in footer: [page number] from [number of pages]?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add style for the header and footer page.

```
<style>
    @page { margin: 180px 50px; }
    #header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: orange; text-align: center; }
    #footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: lightblue; }
    #footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }
</style>
```

Add the `header` part inside this div.

```
<div id="header">

</div>
```

Add `Footer` part in the following div.

```
 <div id="header">

 </div>
```

- Enable `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` from `/config/dompdf.php`
- Publish vendor file via `php artisan vendor:publish` command
- Pass `$pdf` object from controller:
- List item

You should add the following script in the `view` file.

```
<script type="text/php">
    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        // OLD 
        // $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        // $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(255,0,0));
        // v.0.7.0 and greater
        $x = 72;
        $y = 18;
        $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
        $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        $size = 6;
        $color = array(255,0,0);
        $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $angle = 0.0;   //  default
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I add post with new code. Something was wrong. Text is under header. Btw. how can I add to footer page number and total page number?

Comment: @triole For a page number add please see my updated answer.

Comment: You think about something like this: $pdf = new \PDF();
        $data = [
            'pdf' => $pdf,
            'title' => 'tit',
            'heading' => 'Helloż',
            'content' => 'sample txt".'
            ];

        $pdf2 = $pdf::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif', 'defaultPaperSize' => 'a4'])->loadView('psCMS.prints.product-view', $data);
        return $pdf2->download('product-'.$product->id.'-'.now()->toDateString().'.pdf'); ????

Comment: @triole Yes above code is a controller code also used `$pdf` object. So add script in your view file as suggested in answer. Try

Comment: @triole Enable `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` from /config/dompdf.php.

Comment: @triole Which `DOMPDF` version used?

Comment: As in @triole's first comment, the page text starts under the banner. How can I push the text down so that it's visible and content of the page starts after the banner?